# калькулятор unix для сайта

Tags: javascript

Задачку задали такую. Как сделать я незн возможно кто-то подскажет.
Дано:
Арбуз храниться до (unix)1697403600 (15.10.2023) мы знаем что срок хранения 31 день.
Арбуз продали 10.09.2023.
Необходимо узнать с каким % годности был продан арбуз 10.09.2023
Нужно сделать в виде калькулятора. Так же может быть изменен до какого он храниться и когда был продан.

Comment: Данные на вход какие? unix-timestamp или в виде 10.10.2023? Как вы пробовали решить данную задачу и что не получилось?

Comment: Если срок хранения арбуза 31 день, а продали его за 35 дней до конца срока хранения - значит процент будет отрицательный (около минус десяти)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Калькулятор расчета процента годности

Пример кода калькулятора HTML, JavaScript для вычисления процента годности.

HTML:

```
    <p>
        Ввода даты производства:
        <input type="date" id="productionDateInput">
    </p>
    <p>
        Срок годности в днях:
        <input type="number" id="shelfLifeDaysInput" placeholder="Срок годности в днях">
    </p>
    <p>
        Дата продажи:
        <input type="date" id="saleDateInput">
    </p>
    <button id="calculateButton">Рассчитать</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    // Функция для расчета процента годности продукта
    function calculateShelfLifePercentage(productionDate, shelfLifeDays, saleDate) {
        // Преобразование дат в метку времени Unix (секунды с 1 января 1970 года)
        const productionTimestamp = Date.parse(productionDate) / 1000;
        const saleTimestamp = Date.parse(saleDate) / 1000;

        // Рассчитываем срок годности в секундах
        const shelfLifeSeconds = shelfLifeDays * 24 * 60 * 60;

        // Рассчитываем оставшийся срок годности продукта
        const remainingShelfLife = productionTimestamp + shelfLifeSeconds - saleTimestamp;

        // Рассчитываем процент годности
        const shelfLifePercentage = (remainingShelfLife / shelfLifeSeconds) * 100;

        return shelfLifePercentage;
    }

    // Функция для обработки нажатия кнопки
    function calculateAndDisplayResult() {
        const productionDateInput = document.getElementById("productionDateInput");
        const shelfLifeDaysInput = document.getElementById("shelfLifeDaysInput");
        const saleDateInput = document.getElementById("saleDateInput");
        const resultElement = document.getElementById("result");

        const productionDate = productionDateInput.value;
        const shelfLifeDays = parseInt(shelfLifeDaysInput.value);
        const saleDate = saleDateInput.value;

        if (!productionDate || isNaN(shelfLifeDays) || !saleDate) {
            resultElement.textContent = "Пожалуйста, заполните все поля";
            return;
        }

        const percentage = calculateShelfLifePercentage(productionDate, shelfLifeDays, saleDate);
        resultElement.textContent = `Продукт был продан с процентом годности: ${percentage.toFixed(2)}%`;
    }

    // Получаем ссылку на кнопку и добавляем обработчик события
    const calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculateButton");
    calculateButton.addEventListener("click", calculateAndDisplayResult);
```

Пример работы калькулятора представлен в репозитории GitHub:

https://dmitriy-1986.github.io/calculateShelfLifePercentage/

Код калькулятора:

https://github.com/Dmitriy-1986/calculateShelfLifePercentage/blob/main/index.html

Comment: И последнее можно, что бы в "Ввода даты производства:" вводил в поле дату в unix, а все остальные уже в дд.мм.гггг?

Comment: Да, сейчас попробую сделать

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы посчитать процент для начала надо получить количество миллисекунд от начала срока арбуза до покупки, он равен времени покупки минус время начала срока (а он в свою очередь является датой хранения за вычетом срока)

```
function getPercent(elapsedDate, elapsedDays, buyDate) {
  const elapsedMs = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * elapsedDays;
  const buy = buyDate.getTime() - (elapsedDate.getTime() - elapsedMs);
  return buy * 100 / elapsedMs;
};
```

Пользоваться так: `getPercent(new Date(2023, 10, 10), 31, new Date(2023, 9, 23))`

Answer (score 0):

Ввод (Unix timestamp) даты производства в calculateShelfLifePercentage

Теперь в поле "Ввода даты производства (Unix timestamp)" можно вводить дату в формате Unix timestamp, и она будет использоваться при расчете процента годности.

```js
        // Функция для расчета процента годности продукта
        function calculateShelfLifePercentage(productionTimestamp, shelfLifeDays, saleDate) {
            // Преобразование даты продажи в метку времени Unix (секунды с 1 января 1970 года)
            const saleTimestamp = Date.parse(saleDate) / 1000;
        
            // Рассчитываем срок годности в секундах
            const shelfLifeSeconds = shelfLifeDays * 24 * 60 * 60;
        
            // Рассчитываем оставшийся срок годности продукта
            const remainingShelfLife = productionTimestamp + shelfLifeSeconds - saleTimestamp;
        
            // Рассчитываем процент годности
            const shelfLifePercentage = (remainingShelfLife / shelfLifeSeconds) * 100;
        
            return shelfLifePercentage;
        }
        
        // Функция для обработки нажатия кнопки
        function calculateAndDisplayResult() {
            const productionDateInput = document.getElementById("productionDateInput");
            const shelfLifeDaysInput = document.getElementById("shelfLifeDaysInput");
            const saleDateInput = document.getElementById("saleDateInput");
            const resultElement = document.getElementById("result");
        
            const productionTimestamp = parseInt(productionDateInput.value);
            const shelfLifeDays = parseInt(shelfLifeDaysInput.value);
            const saleDate = saleDateInput.value;
        
            if (isNaN(productionTimestamp) || isNaN(shelfLifeDays) || !saleDate) {
                resultElement.textContent = "Пожалуйста, заполните все поля корректными данными";
                return;
            }
        
            const percentage = calculateShelfLifePercentage(productionTimestamp, shelfLifeDays, saleDate);
            resultElement.textContent = `Продукт был продан с процентом годности: ${percentage.toFixed(2)}%`;
        }
        
        // Получаем ссылку на кнопку и добавляем обработчик события
        const calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculateButton");
        calculateButton.addEventListener("click", calculateAndDisplayResult);
```

```html
        <p>
            Ввода даты производства (Unix timestamp):
            <input type="text" id="productionDateInput" placeholder="Дата в формате Unix timestamp">
            
        </p>
        <p>
            Срок годности в днях:
            <input type="number" id="shelfLifeDaysInput" placeholder="Срок годности в днях">
        </p>
        <p>
            Дата продажи:
            <input type="date" id="saleDateInput">
        </p>
        <button id="calculateButton">Рассчитать</button>
        <div id="result"></div>
```